# Finding arrays within arrays

Tags: ruby, arrays

I have an array of hashes, some of which are subsets of others.

```
a = []
a << {Bob: 1, Mary: 2, Sue: 3}
a << {Bob:1}
a << {Phil: 2, Brian: 8}
a << {Bob: 1, Mary: 2, Sue: 3, Tony: 9}
```

I need to return an array of the unique super-sets which, in this case, would be:

```
{Bob: 1, Mary: 2, Sue: 3, Tony: 9}
{Phil: 2, Brian: 8}
```

I read ["Ruby Array Comparison Tricks"](http://blog.hulihanapplications.com/browse/view/28-ruby-array-comparison-tricks) however it doesn't offer what I require.

Is there a Ruby solution to compare arrays and identify sub-arrays?

Comment: What code have you written? Are you *always* keying off the first name/value pair?

Comment: You might be able to simplify things by using sets http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.5/libdoc/set/rdoc/Set.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know a great algorithm for this, but the brute force solution is pretty simple in Ruby: use the `-` operator to find the complement of one array in another, then check if it's empty. With casting so it works with hashes too, the code is something like

```
def superset?(ary1, ary2)
  ary1 != ary2 && (ary2.to_a - ary1.to_a) == []
end

def maximal_sets(arrays)
  arrays.reject{ |ary2| arrays.any?{ |ary1| superset?(ary1, ary2) } }
end
```